# un-interruptible function in C++

Tags: c++, android-ndk

I have a couple of functions that do async communication over SPI using ioctl calls.

These functions are very quick to execute because the data payloads are only a few bytes - however - it is imperative that the timing isn't interrupted.

I noticed that these functions are sometimes interrupted as the CPU services other threads - this ends up breaking the async communication; it changes the timing.

For these two functions how can I specify that they may not be interrupted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with a regular program on most normal OS's ( like windows, OsX, linux). If you could, then malware could lock up your machine by simply declaring an infinite loop to be un-interruptible. It might be possible to do something like this in a device driver. If you really need this level of control there are real-time OSs for that.

I think you can do this in Linux in a Kernel module.

Comment: +1 and agree, if you have to go *that* low-level that you can access an SPI kernel driver from user-mode you can as well write your own kernel-module and free yourself from all the user-mode restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling all interrupts is difficult and dangerous (and subject to breaking with kernel updates) -- you should avoid doing so unless it's absolutely necessary. For SPI you should rely on drivers that handle the timing and kernel configuration like the andriod serial library.

I've tried implementing the protocols and timing on microcontrollers (when I needed different SPIs with different speeds simultaneously on two sets of pins) -- it's hard to get perfect even without the multi-threading issues. So you should really ask yourself, should I be implementing low level communication calls myself.

I realize this doesn't actually answer your question as to how to disable all interrupts, but I feel it addresses your end goal all the same.